# Confirm email link not hidden in plain text client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I've got a MVC web app with the built in Auth. I'm using SendGrid to send an email requesting the user to confirm their email address. All is well in Browser email clients. In Outlook's Desktop client the link to confirm the email is not hidden.

I'm using SendGrid 9.16.0.0

In my IndentityConfig.cs I see this:

```
 var plainTextContent = message.Body;
        var htmlContent = message.Body;
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
```

I see my htmlContent and plainTextContent are the same. I don't know where the message.Body is populated or more importantly how/where to create the proper plain text version? Or is there some other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to hide the link? Maybe I've missed the point somehow

Comment: I didn't word it well, In Outlook Desktop the link expands to show the URL instead of just "click here" underlined. A local friend told me that this behavior happens in Outlook when an email ends up in the junk email folder?

Comment: That's because plain-text emails cannot show hyperlinks. The plain-text format has no way to create a piece of text which points to a URL in the background. That feature simple does not exist in plain-text. It only exists in HTML. But Outlook can be configured to show emails in HTML by default, it is not required to use plain-text.

Comment: (I haven't noticed the behaviour being specific to the junk folder, but that would actually make sense as a security feature, because plain-text format cannot contain malicious images or scripts etc which could be lurking in the HTML format, so if a message is regarded as potentially suspicious then it would be a lot safer to show it in plain text initially.)